How do I delete tunnels on the localhost (lo0) interface?
How do I delete tunnels on the localhost (lo0) interface? I have tunnels on my machine, but no active VPNs, so it seems like they shouldn’t be there. How do I delete these tunnel interfaces and routes?



Those tunnel interfaces are created by macOS for features/services like Find My, OpenVPN, etc.  It is definitely  not recommended to delete, but even if you do, they will be recreated on the next reboot.
There are a number of interfaces that get created see this answer: Surprisingly many network interfaces on macOS: are these legitimate?
